# how to make droppable the tree node in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, drag-and-drop, datatable, tree

I have p:panelGrid component which consists of two components - p:tree and p:dataTable. The issue concerns in impossibility to drag the element of data table and drop in tree node - is that possible. In advance, thanks a lot for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag and drop for tree nodes is not supported at this point by primefaces. However, in this [page](http://primefaces.org/funding.html) you can see that it's a feature request in community funding. when donations for that feature reach $1000 it will be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Treenode drag and drop worked earlier.©  2009-2010  •  Prime Technology.Running PrimeFaces-3.0-SNAPSHOT on Mojarra-2.0.why this feature was removed?any answer